# How to replace a text pattern with a variable

Tags: regex, sas

I know how to use `prxchange()` to replace text in some pattern. But it is stricted with constant string or some special format(like *upcase* or *lowcase*). Do you know how to replace text in pattern with a variable? Please show me some example.

Comment: Provide some examples of the data and replacements to be performed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming you mean to ask how to replace a variable name demarcated in a string.

**Perl** has interpolation, **SAS** does not.

You will have to choose a demarcating scheme and then using `PRXNEXT` to find the *token* within for replacement with a variable value.

Example:

Variable names are demarcated as `#<variable-name>#`.

Code:

```
data want;
  array patterns(6) $100 _temporary_
  ( 'The student name is #name#'
  , 'I was #name#''s lab partner'
  , '#name# is a swell fella'
  , 'This won''t work. Next year #name# will be #age#'
  , '#name# is #height# inches tall'
  , '#000#, not a #replacable variable#. #name# is.'
  );

  set sashelp.class;
  where sex='M';

  * pattern to discover a token, i.e. a demarcated variable name;
  id = prxparse('/#([_a-z][_a-z0-9]*)#/i');

  do index = 1 to dim(patterns);

    length result $200;
    result = patterns(index);

    do start=1 to length(result);

      call prxnext(id, start, -1, result, pos, len);

      if pos = 0 then leave;

      * extract variable name from token;
      varname = prxposn(id,1,result);

      * replace token with the formatted value of the variable;
      result = transtrn(result, cats('#',varname,'#'), strip(vvaluex(varname)));

    end;

    output;
  end;

  keep name result;
run;
```

Comment: That is a feasible solution, thanks Richard. I have been too busy last week to review my question